# wso2 scim api for password checking

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 Identity Server for usernames and password. I am using WSO2 SCIM APIs for updating/resetting the user's password using the PATCH. 
In the UI, the user has to enter the old password and new password. 
But while resetting the user's password, I have to first verify users current password. Is there an API to verify the password in WSO2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `getMe` endpoint and act based on the response.

```
curl -v -k --user [username]:[password] https://localhost:9443/scim2/Me
```

Ref: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS560/apidocs/SCIM2-endpoints/#!/operations#MeEndpoint#getUserMe